# Logging into Twitter using the C libcurl library

Tags: c, twitter, libcurl

I have spent days trying to figure this out without luck..
I am able to log into other websites but not Twitter and its driving me nuts!

I won't post my entire program, just the parts that matter.
(I will abstract out some parts for your sake)

```
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );

    CURL * myHandle = curl_easy_init ( );
    CURLcode result;
    OutputBuffer output;

    /* Fetch Login page to parse authenticity token */

    // Set up a couple initial paramaters that we will not need to mofiy later.
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0");
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1 );
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &output);
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");

    // Visit the login page once to obtain a PHPSESSID cookie
    curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.twitter.com/login/");
    result = curl_easy_perform( myHandle );



   // assume that the program properly retrieves the authenticity token here and stores it in 'token'
   // then creates 'char *postreq' with the following format:
   // session[username_or_email]=EnterUsername&session[password]=EnterPassword&remember_me=1&return_to_ssl=true&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=true&authenticity_token=TokenGoesHere&ui_metrics=off&ui_metrics_seed=1450307791003



    /*********************************************************************************************************/

// perform login 

        // set the post fields
        curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, postreq);

        // forge the HTTP referer field, or HTS will deny the login
        curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.twitter.com/login/sessions");

        result = curl_easy_perform( myHandle );

        printf("%s", output.buffer);


        return 0;
    }
```

I know it is failing because I print out the resulting web page and I filter through the keyword "logout" (which only should appear when logged in) and it is never found.
I have no clue what I am doing wrong.. it works for other websites :/

Please do not tell me to use the Twitter API! 
I strictly want to do this using C and libcurl w/out the API.

My logic so far:
Phase 1:
- fetch login page
- parse authenticity token
- save session cookie to file

Phase 2:
- build POST request: session[username_or_email]=EnterUsername&session[password]=EnterPassword&authenticity_token=TokenGoesHere
- load cookie from file
- perform login

I've looked everywhere and I can't figure it out..
any guidance is truly appreciated!

PS. is my POST request format correct for Twitter? Or is it missing something?

Answer (score 2):

To start with, I believe you're sending the POST to the wrong URL (see the action="" parameter to the form tag). Then I also think you should avoid closing/recreating the easy handle as that's just extra overhead.

But in more general terms: fire up your network tool in your browser (Firefox or Chrome) and record what it does when you go to the page manually and then login. You especially check the GET of the login form page and the POST where the browser logs in.

Then you take that knowledge and doublecheck that your libcurl-using application works the same way. It can then be useful to use [DEBUGFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION.html) to get a full trace of everything libcurl sends and receives so that you can check that is very similar to your browser's actions.

Comment: I am now using the "https://twitter.com/login/sessions" URL as the target.
I also added a few more parameters to my post request : &remember_me=1&return_to_ssl=true&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=true

But still will not work. The reason I close the handle is so that the curl COOKIEJAR "method" will output the cookie to the "cookie.txt" file. otherwise it doesn't. Could this be an issue?

Also I tried using wireshark before but miserably failed to accomplish anything.

Comment: You need to add all fields the form has, including hidden ones. You don't need the jar file saved if you reuse the handle, as curl keep saved cookies "in the handle" as well so the second request would use the correct ones. Again: compare the browser's and libcurl's requests.

Comment: I changed it so that it does not cleanup the handle after the first 'perform'. Do I leave the COOKIE file inputs as "cookie.txt" or do I set them to "-" for COOKIEJAR and "" for COOKIEFILE ?

Also, I updated the format to:
session[username_or_email]=user&session[password]=password&remember_me=1&scribe_log=&redirect_after_login=true&authenticity_token=6e706165609354bd7a92a99cf94e09140ea86c6f&ui_metrics=off&ui_metrics_seed=1450307791003

...that should be including everything from the action="https://twitter.com/sessions/" form

Comment: Can you please double check and confirm if I am setting the fields correctly?
Also, the metric seed is random every page load... do I need to scrape that from the HTML and set it correctly or can I use  generic number?

PS. thank you so much for your help, I truly appreciate it